# I'm not able to getLoginStatus

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to do the following simple facebook integration:

I just want to read the previously authorized app status, either connected or not authorized I want to deal with the result.

But I am getting the error `FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()`. Which makes sense assuming `.init` didn't finished while I called `getLoginStatus`.

How to solve this without having to add async dynamic js reference?

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'myappid', // App ID
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });
        };


        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            alert(response.status);
            if (response.status == "connected") {
                $("#lkLogin").css("display", "none");
                $("#spUser").css("display", "inline");

                $("#spUser").html(response.name);

            } else if (response.status == "not_authorized") {
                $("#lkLogin").css("display", "inline");
                $("#spUser").css("display", "none");
            }
        });

    });
</script>

<a href="#" id="lkLogin" style="display:inline;">Facebook Login</a>
<span id="spUser" style="display:none;"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function `FB.getLoginStatus()` just after you called `FB.init()`; since the `init()` is called asynch. So what's happening is that, `FB` is not initialized before the `getLoginstatus()` is called; hence you should call it synch like this-

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
         appId: 'myappid', // App ID
         status: true, // check login status
         cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
     });

     // call FB.getloginstatus function here
};
```

Answer (score -2):

This should do it:

```
<script language="javascript">


            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({
                    appId: 'myappid', // App ID
                    status: true, // check login status
                    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                    xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
                });
            };

    $(document).ready(function () {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                alert(response.status);
                if (response.status == "connected") {
                    $("#lkLogin").css("display", "none");
                    $("#spUser").css("display", "inline");

                    $("#spUser").html(response.name);

                } else if (response.status == "not_authorized") {
                    $("#lkLogin").css("display", "inline");
                    $("#spUser").css("display", "none");
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

    <a href="#" id="lkLogin" style="display:inline;">Facebook Login</a>
    <span id="spUser" style="display:none;"></span>
```

Comment: it doesn't make any sense

Comment: If the `FB.init()` is outside of `$(document).ready` it will be called first.  Then FB methods can be used anywhere, instead of just within the `fbAsyncInit` function.